# SQL DB Calls in dll or inside project?

Tags: sql, dll

This may seem like an elementary question, or one that may not have a finite answer, in which I apologize.

My question is what are the major pluses and/or minus for having database calls (SQL in my case) in an DLL (its own project) vs. having them inside the project/website with the application (in like a app_code folder for example). All of the DB calls are for this one particular application ONLY, there are no other applications that need to look at this DLL. I'm not sure why my predecessor did this, and trying to understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's just a general good practice to layer your application.

The actual layering can be done using various techniques:

using namespaces, creating DLL's, using folders within the project, putting each layer on a different fysical machine (although this is technically also a different "tier")

Your predecessor just chose to put it in a different DLL, so that he would later have the flexibility to reuse the DLL in its entirety. Although it's only for one project, you never know.

As they say: it doesn't cost anything to create a class, the same goes for a DLL. (not counting minor performance differences)